# Since upgrading to 19.10, composing accented characters has changed

Tags: keyboard, 19.10

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10. Before that point, the key sequence <kbd>compose key</kbd>-<kbd>'</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> would let me type an `é` character. Now it creates `ê` instead. To compose e-acute I need <kbd>compose key</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>.

Is there a reason this should have changed? The docs still seem to say that the original key-sequence I was using is still the correct one. Where are such key-mappings defined?

For reference, I'm using a UK layout keyboard.